# How to overwrite contents of a file without deleting existing contents in Java?

Tags: java

I don't want to append and I don't want to truncate existing data. I want to overwrite existing data. For example, the following code leaves the test.txt file containing "hello" but I want the file to contain "hello6789".

```
try(
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("test.txt"); ){
   fw.write("123456789");
}    
try(
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("test.txt"); ){
   fw.write("hello");
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Open for `r+`, set cursor to 0.

Comment: Is that in Java? I though the append mode was a boolean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) which was added in Java 7.
(Note that below code also uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).)

```java
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class Proj2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("test.txt");
        try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path,
                                                         StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                         StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
            bw.write("123456789");
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
        try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path,
                                                         StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                         StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
            bw.write("hello");
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Contents of file *test.txt* after running above code:

```
hello6789
```

Also refer to *javadoc* for [enum] [StandardOpenOption](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html).

Comment: But it should be noted that in-place rewriting of a file *may* leave the file corrupted if the application ... or OS ... dies at an inopportune instant.

Comment: Might be useful to add `TRUNCATE_EXISTING` in the first case to show the difference.